# Cat comes back after 4 days, meows loud, and wants to go back outside again

Tags: cats, psychology

My cat (female) left us 4 days ago and didn't came until today. When she came back she was dirty, didn't want to be touched, didn't want to eat or drink even though it was very warm outside. After like 2 minutes with us, she started consistently meowing and giving us signs she want to go back outside again.

Is this normal? Is there something wrong with her?

Comment: Please don't be insulted by this question, ratherCatPerson, but she is spayed, right? (And microchipped?)

Answer (score 6):

You have a serious choice to make.  Cats who go outside are far more independent than purely indoor cats.  Once you allow a cat to go outside regularly, there are lots of factors to consider.

1. Once a cat goes "outdoors" they expect the freedom to do so and wont be happy unless they can.  I believe this is why your cat is wanting to go back out.
2. Outdoor cats have half the lifespan of indoor cats.  They will pick up parasites like fleas, ticks, worms, and other nasty things.  They are far more susceptible to diseases, like rabies.  They will fight with other cats, animals, and have a risk of being hit by cars.  There is a much higher risk of injury and death.
3. It is not uncommon for outdoor domestic cats to adopt another human family and be taken in by them.
4. Cats are natural predators.  Next to humans, outdoor domestic cats are the biggest threat to wildlife.  Outdoor cats are the leading cause of death among both birds and mammals in the United States, according to a new study, killing 1.4 billion to 3.7 billion birds each year.
5. Outdoor female cats that arent spayed are far more likely to have an unplanned pregnancy.

Simply put, you have to consider the fact that by letting your cat outside, your cat might not come back.  You should seriously consult your vet to decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The same happend with most of my cats. Usually they leave home only for a couple of hours but sometimes they are off for days without cause. After two or three days I start to search them and one I found near a little creek happily playing around and not really willing to come home. Another was at a construction place where they build a new house. She seemed to love the wet cement. After that adventure they acted as before. It is really a strange behaviour which emerges now and then.

Answer (score 0):

The Humane Society has a page on [bringing outdoor cats indoors](http://www.humanesociety.org/animals/cats/tips/bringing_outside_cat_indoors.html) and [keeping indoor cats happy](http://www.humanesociety.org/animals/cats/tips/cat_happy_indoors.html) which may be applicable to your situation.  Likewise, the ASPCA has a page about [preventing a cat from getting out](http://www.aspca.org/pet-care/virtual-pet-behaviorist/cat-behavior/preventing-your-cat-getting-outside) as well as a more general article on [cat enrichment](http://www.aspca.org/pet-care/virtual-pet-behaviorist/cat-behavior/enriching-your-cats-life).

The main idea across all of these articles is to make indoor life interesting and stimulating for your cat by providing opportunities for your cat to exercise its natural behaviors.  By satisfying your cat's needs and desires to run, climb, hide, scratch, and hunt, you can reduce your cat's desire to escape and ensure your cat is contented and healthy without the risks and dangers associated with unrestricted outdoor access.